# Errors while building my ROS node

Tags: c++, ros

I am new to ROS...and trying to create a simple random number generator, which will publish the randomly generated values. For this I created a Position class :

```
include "stdlib.h"

namespace RandomPositionGenerator {


class Position {
private:
double x;
double y;
double z;
public:
Position();
void setPosition();
void getPosition(double &a, double &b, double &c);
};

Position::Position(){}

void Position::setPosition() {
x = rand();
y = rand();
z = rand();
}

void Position::getPosition(double &a, double &b, double &c) {
 a=x;
 b=y;
 c=z;

}

}
```

and used this class to create my publisher :

```
include "ros/ros.h"
include "std_msgs/String.h"
include "sstream"
include "Position.cpp"

/**
 * This method generates position coordinates at random.
**/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher position_pub = n.advertise<RandomPositionGenerator:: Position>      ("position", 50);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    double pos_x=0;
    double pos_y=0;
    double pos_z=0;

    while (ros::ok())
    {
   RandomPositionGenerator:: Position pos;
   pos.setPosition();
   pos.getPosition(pos_x,pos_y,pos_z);

       ROS_INFO("The co-ordinates are : x=",pos_x);

       position_pub.publish(pos);
       ros::spinOnce();
       loop_rate.sleep();

    }


   return 0;
}
```

And now I get the following errors:

1. ‘__s_getDataType’ is not a member of ‘RandomPositionGenerator::Position’
2. ‘__s_getMD5Sum’ is not a member of ‘RandomPositionGenerator::Position’
3. ‘const class RandomPositionGenerator::Position’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’

and some more similar errors...Please correct me...I am not sure where am I going wrong, or if there is anything that I did right in this small bit of code !

Comment: Seems like some kind of build problem...there's not enough information here to see what went wrong.  (You didn't show the lines of code that generated those error messages...that might help.)  But `#include "Position.cpp"` looks like an issue -- it is highly unusual to `#include` source code (.cpp as opposed to .h) files; you're supposed to compile them separately and combine them using the linker.  I am unfamiliar with the ROS API, but I wonder if you've tried to redefine an internal `Position` class that implements the missing methods, or if you're supposed to inherit them from somewhere?

Comment: I think ROS msgs don't allow my custom class Position to be a valid msg_type bcz it is missing these members....but I don't know where to find them or how to implement them in my class Position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an actual ROS message instead of a custom class for data that you'd like to publish/subscribe to. See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv for how to create a new message that you can then use when publishing data. Using a ROS message also means that existing ROS tools such as `rostopic` and entire language bindings such as `rospy` for Python or `rosjava` for Java will be able to easily interoperate with your C++ node.

For this particular case, you can simply use the standard ROS message for a 3D point, [geometry_msgs/Point](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point.html). You can find a fairly comprehensive list of the standardized messages in the [common_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/common_msgs?distro=hydro) documentation. Using a standardized message has a number of benefits over creating your own message with essentially the same content - the biggest is that there are many tools or other pieces of software in the ROS ecosystem that you may want to take advantage of later, which will be a fairly painless process if you are already using standarized message types.

If you really have a need to use your custom Position class (without simply converting it to a ROS message), you can look at the [roscpp serialization](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes) documentation. I would *strongly* suggest against serializing your custom class instead of using either an actual ROS message that you create or a standardized message.

Comment: Yea...This is the best approach I guess...and thanku very much for thee pointers...really helpful.Thanks ! :)